# how do i transfer a label to another container

Tags: javascript, c#

i would like to transfer a generated label into another container which is the flowLayoutpanel. there's a button that will generate the label and i added a click event on the generated label but idk how to move them out of the panel and transport to flowlayoutpanel.

thank you for your future answers.

````
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            lbl.Top = y;
            lbl.Left = l1;
            lbl.Text = "a " + l1.ToString();
            lbl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lbl.Width = 40;
            lbl.Click += new EventHandler(lbl_Click);
            return lbl;
        }

        void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label lblclk = (Label)sender;
            lblclk.Parent = new FlowLayoutPanel();// i know this part was wrong 

        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1, then the click event will first remove it from panel1 and then add it to the flowLayoutPanel1.

```
    private void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblclk = sender as Label;
        panel1.Controls.Remove(lblclk);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblclk);
    }
```

Comment: @JOSEPHSIXSON... Good to hear... It is customary to mark the solution that you feel worked for you as the solution. This give points to the answerer and helps the community too. Thanks!